# Only want part of an STL

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

I am using different STLs to make a special creature.  For example: I have a panther STL, but only want to use the head for my project, and then just the wings from another STL, etc.

Is there an easy way to separate the parts I need?  I have looked through some other Q&A and found some things that are close, but I have yet to find the best solution.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to the site :) Let us know if the linked answers don't satisfactorily answer your question.

Comment: That link was helpful.  Thank you.